# cannot convert argument from 'int' to 'int &'

Tags: c++, recursion

```
void cnt_cif(int n, int k, int &c)
{
    if (n != 0)
    {
        if (n % 10 > k)
            cnt_cif(n / 10, k, c + 1);
    }
}

int main()
{
    int n, k, c=0;

    cin >> n >> k;

    cnt_cif(n, k, c);

    cout << c;

    return 0;
   }
```

Errors

```
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   C2664   'void cnt_cif(int,int,int &)': cannot convert argument 3 from 'int' to 'int &'  


Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error (active)  E0461   initial value of reference to non-const must be an lvalue
```

the problem seems to be at line 11

Comment: Your function never modifies `c`. So it doesn't make any sense that `c` should be a reference. As for the error, a reference can not be bound to an "expression" like `c + 1`. Consider using *return values* instead.

Comment: Why are you using a reference?

Comment: What is this even meant to do? You aren't returning anything from the recursive function.

Comment: i have to count the number of digits greater than k from n using c

Answer (score 2):

To use `c` as an output parameter, you need to reassign it in the function. Then you can pass the updated variable when you make the recursive call.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

void cnt_cif(int n, int k, int &c)
{
    if (n != 0)
    {
        if (n % 10 > k) {
            c++;
            cnt_cif(n / 10, k, c);
        }
    }
}

int main()
{
    int n, k, c=0;

    cin >> n >> k;

    cnt_cif(n, k, c);

    cout << c << '\n';

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: not related to the asked question per se, but try the input `654321 4`

Comment: @Default Yeah, he only recurses when the last digit is greater than `k`. He never explained what the function is really supposed to do.

Comment: he did in a comment: *i have to count the number of digits greater than k from n using c*

Answer (score 1):

An r-value like `c+1` cannot initialize an l-value reference like `c` The pre-increment operator `++` returns a reference, so you can use that in place of `c+1`. Whether of not fixing that makes a function that does what you want is another question.

```
#include <iostream>

void cnt_cif(int n, int k, int &c)
{
    if (n >= 0)
    {
        if (n % 10 > k) {
            cnt_cif(n / 10, k, ++c);
        }
    }
}

int main()
{
    int n, k, c = 0;

    std::cin >> n >> k;

    cnt_cif(n, k, c);

    std::cout << c;

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm sorry for vague details. I figured it out finally

```
void cnt_cif(int n, int k, int &c)
{
if (n != 0)
{
    if (n % 10 > k)
        cnt_cif(n / 10, k, ++c);
    else
        cnt_cif(n / 10, k, c);
}
}

int main()
{
int n, k, c=0;

cin >> n >> k;

cnt_cif(n, k, c);

cout << c;

return 0;
}
```

Comment: Almost. The sad fact is that `n % 10` does not "do the right thing" when n is negative.

Comment: Are you *sure* `c` is *always* increased before `cnt_cif` is called in the first case? It would be if passed by value. C++ is tricky in this area. @StoryTeller will know, and might even answer, particularly if an upvote is promised.

Comment: @Bathsheba - It's fine even for a pass by reference. http://eel.is/c++draft/intro.execution#11.sentence-1

Comment: @Bathsheba It is. unary prefix increment performs the increment and [returns a reference to the incremented ident](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_incdec), all of which will take place prior to the invoke.

Answer (score -1):

Maybe this is what you meant? 
**EDITED** to sort out the logic as highlighted by @Default

```
int cnt_cif(int n, int k)
{
    int c;
    if (n != 0) {
        c = (n % 10 > k) ? 1 : 0;
        return cnt_cif(n / 10, k) + c;
    }
    return 0;
}

int main()
{
    int n, k;
    cin >> n >> k;
    cout << cnt_cif(n, k);
    return 0;
}
```

**EDIT 2**

For what it is worth, and if anyone is interested, the above has been modified to remain tail-recursive. In addition, it has been modified to ensure that even negative values of `n` are handled correctly.

```
int cnt_cif(int n, int k)
{
    int m = n < 0 ? -n : n;
    int c = (m != 0 && m % 10 > k) ? 1 : 0;
    return (m == 0) ? 0 : c + cnt_cif(m / 10, k);
}

int main()
{
    int n, k;
    cin >> n >> k;
    cout << cnt_cif(n, k);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: @Default - You were right. I have adjusted my code so it works.

Comment: I didn't downvote either, but an unfortunate consequence of this is that we no longer have a tail recursion. That may or may not affect the resulting optimized program, and should be mentioned.

Comment: @StoryTeller: I am unsure exactly how unfortunate the absence of tail recursion is, given that the OP never mentioned anything other than that they had to use recursion. Moveover, the OP is using `int` values, which, for the task at hand would severely limit the number of recursions required, and performance wouldn't really become a factor.

Comment: @PeterAbolins - Given the OP's very basic misunderstandings, I don't think the tail-recursion-friendly signature is their own idea. If that is indeed a criteria (I speculate of course), this solution will fail them in their assignment. I'm not saying it's bad to make it a simpler to read recursion. I'm just saying such a transformation warrants at least a mention, is all.

Comment: @StoryTeller. To be honest, if I were writing this myself, I would write it differently (more robustly). The idea here is to present a solution which doesn't have the bug they mentioned in their title. Is it perfect? No. Is it intended to make them think? Yes.

Answer (score -2):

So you are trying to pass `c` to the function, which calls itself in a recursive way and then print your `c` after the recursions has ended. Your approach for this seems to be passing `c` down every call to store the result in it. Your problem, that also causes the error is, that the signature of your function `void cnt_cif(int n, int k, int &c)` takes a pointer to an int as its third parameter but in main you give it an int value.

```
int n, k, c=0;
cnt_cif(n, k, c);
```

what you instead need to do is to give it the pointer to the value

```
cnt_cif(n, k, &c);
```

an also in your function change the value of `c` an then again use the pointer as the parameter

```
if (n != 0){
    if (n % 10 > k){
        c += 1;
        cnt_cif(n / 10, k, &c);
    }
}
```

A function a value as a parameter it is copied and any changes to the value inside the function have no effect on the initial value. If you use a pointer as a parameter the pointer is copied but the value it points to is the exact same and changes to that will affect the original.

Comment: @Default `&` gives the pointer to a value. 
`The address of a variable can be obtained by preceding the name of a variable with an ampersand sign (&), known as address-of operator.`
from [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/pointers/)

Comment: Also the function signature hints at the missing `&`

Comment: @Default is right. That usage of `&` has nothing at all to do with pointers.

Comment: oh well then @JiveDadson, teach me please. Or Default maybe. I´d like to understand my misconception here

Comment: That use of & denotes a reference.  There are various kinds. This one is a non-const lvalue reference. It creates a local alias for the function argument. Any intro to C++ book will cover this. Here's a technical gloss: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/reference_initialization

Comment: @Default When we were discussing adding references to the language, I told Bjarne (the onlie begetter) that people would confuse references with pointers. Parsimony prevailed over clarity.

Comment: @JiveDadson - There's also the unfortunate influence of implementations that implement pointers and references with the same means, and contribute to the confusion further.